# Adding a week to date javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a JSfiddle which I am trying to add a week onto a date. The date is outputting incorrect date when I try to add six days.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Pcfk/6/)

code for adding a week

```
 var endDate =  new Date(date || Date.now()),
            eMonth = '' + (monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]),
            eDay = '' + (endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 6)),
            eYear = endDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: `endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 6)` this return the endDate (+6 days) in millisecond. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
var endDate = new Date(date || Date.now());
var days = 6;
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + days);

var eMonth = '' + (monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]),
    eDay = '' + endDate.getDate(),
    eYear = endDate.getFullYear();
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Pcfk/11/)

Comment: thanks, will the months work correctly with this method. this is going to be my next task

Answer (score 0):

```
eDay = '' + (endDate.getDate() + 6)
```

Remove `setDate()` function and change `$("#startDate").text(startDate)` to show value in span tag

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
var endDate =  new Date(date || Date.now());
endDate.setTime(startDateObj.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
var newDate = endDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(endDate.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+endDate.getDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the get/set Time methods:

```
var today = new Date();
var plusOneWeek = new Date();
plusOneWeek.setTime( today.getTime()+(7*24*3600*1000) ); //add 7 days
```

See the doc about `getTime()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: The problem I see here - is that in case DST happens (clock goes forward 1 hour) within the next 7 days period - adding that amount of milliseconds would land you still at 23:00 of the 6th day... and not on 00:00 of the 7th day...

Answer (score -1):

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var oneWeek = 6*24*60*60*1000;
var newDate = now+oneWeek;
alert(new Date(newDate));
```

this should do the work